# AngularJS http post and redirect to payment gateway

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS, I want to post a set of data and get redirect to a payment url. I have added the following function and a directive to achieve this.

However I can't achieve the same and got following two errors `$interpolate:interr` and `TypeError: element.submit is not a function` error.

How to solve the error reported by AngularJS? I am novice with AngularJS, so couldn't understand whats happening.

```
$scope.transaction = function () {
    var data = $scope.details;
    var formData = {
        redirectUrl: 'https://payment-gateway-url',
        redirectMethod: 'POST',
        redirectData: {
            id: data.id,
            para1: data.para1
        }
    };
    $rootScope.$broadcast('gateway.redirect', formData);
    $scope.$emit('gateway.redirect');
};

app.directive('autoSubmitForm', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        template: '<form action="{{formData.redirectUrl}}" method="{{formData.redirectMethod}}">' +
            '<div><input name="{{key}}" type="hidden" value="{{val}}" /></div>' +
            '</form>',
        link: function($scope, element, $attrs) {
            $scope.$on($attrs['event'], function(event, data) {
                $scope.formData = data;
                console.log('redirecting now!');
                $timeout(function() {
                    element.submit();
                })
             })
        }
    }
}]);

<div auto-submit-form event="gateway.redirect"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the directive is not interpolating the values of *action*, *method*, *name* and *value* in the template. And the *element* is referring to the div where the directive is defined, so element is not really the form. You can try it in the way I show you in the plunker. I generate the form dynamically and at the end I submit it with jQuery.

```
app.directive('autoSubmitForm', ['$interpolate', function($interpolate) {
  return {
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      formData: '='
    },
    template: '',
    link: function($scope, element, $attrs) {
      $scope.$on($attrs['event'], function(event, data) {
        var form = $interpolate('<form action="{{formData.redirectUrl}}" method="{{formData.redirectMethod}}"><div><input name="id" type="text" type="hidden" value="{{formData.redirectData.id}}"/></div></form>')($scope);
        console.log(form);
        jQuery(form).appendTo('body').submit();
      })
    }
  }
}]);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/OUu9XgtMttPCri3KvapJ?p=preview

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the update. It solved the problem of redirection.